# Pass a data provider within a data provider

Tags: java, excel, selenium, testng

I am currently building an object driven script which has associated actions and data in an excel sheet. I am reading this excel sheet into the data provider and passing it as an input to the @Test method where I have if loops to handle the various actions. The code looks like this at high level

```
@DataProvider(name="DP")    
  Reads excel file with actions from Sheet1
@Test(dataprovider = "DP")
   if(Action="Click") 
      Perform Action
   else if(Action="SetText")
      Set Text in Text Box
    ........
 @AfterTest
   Read data to excel file with status for each action
```

The problem now is I have been asked to create separate functions for commonly performed actions say Login functionality etc. and store them in Sheet2

So now my Sheet1 which works as the driver script has a mixture of both Functions and Actions, where if it is Function -> Go to Sheet2, execute the actions in Sheet2 for that function, come back to Sheet1 execute Individual actions/ functions again and so on.

I tried implementing this using multiple data providers, but my code structure does not allow me for a good implementation of the same. Any pointers on how I can achieve this please?

Answer (score 0):

TestNG `DataProviders` are source of data not actions. Just stop here. Forget about excel-driven framework. Build normal actions, data sources and scenarios.